# isc-dhcp leases file never cleaned

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

When running isc-dhcp the leases file seems to grow indefinitely (several hundred MB). If I restart the isc-dhcp service, the file shrinks to 1.5MB.

How can I have isc-dhcp flush expired records periodically without restarting the full service?

Comment: The documentation suggests `dhcpd` does this itself automatically, but at a frequency of its choosing.  How long are your leases?  Is there a good business reason not to just bounce the daemon?

Comment: I use fairly short leases. I don't want to crontab a service restart, since truncating a large leases file seems to take a min - leaving the DHCP service off for the duration

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use longer leases?  That would prevent the file from growing so fast.

Comment: It's only a workaround for DHCP scope running full.

Comment: It's only a workaround if there's a business reason to use short leases; otherwise, you're running misconfigured, and upset that the daemon won't clean up after you.

Comment: "The documentation suggests dhcpd does this itself automatically, but at a frequency of its choosing" -- URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16857/discussion-between-jon-skarpeteig-and-madhatter).

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, from `man dhcpd.leases`: "*In  order to prevent the lease database from growing without bound, the file is rewritten from time to time.*".  But Jenny D has provided an excellent answer (as usual!), and I think no further input is required of me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As MadHatter mentioned in a comment, the leases file is periodically re-created to avoid this problem. While the period isn't mentioned in the documentation, discussions [on the dhcp-users mailinglist](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2010-September/012274.html) indicates that it should be done once an hour, and I've checked the source code and found that this is correct.

Unfortunately this isn't a configurable option. In order to change it, you'd need to compile the dhcp server from source. In the file `server/db.c` you'd need to change the line

```
#define LEASE_REWRITE_PERIOD 3600
```

to the number of seconds you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to my question [How do I purge dhcpd.leases](https://serverfault.com/questions/955966/how-do-i-purge-dhcpd-leases).  In my case the ownership of /var/lib/dhcp was root:root owing to a bug in isc-dhcp-server.  Changing it to dhcpd:dhcpd fixes the problem temporarily, but it comes back when dhcpd restarts.