# How do I purge dhcpd.leases?

Tags: isc-dhcp

I'm running DHCPD (isc-dhcp-4.2.4) on an Ubuntu 14.04 system.  The var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases file is getting pretty huge (350MB).  Looking in it, there's historical data going back many months about leases that have long since expired.  How do I purge the old info?  Presumably stopping dhcpd and deleting the file is a bad idea because then it will forget recent leases that might still be relevant?

[edit] Apparently dhcpd is supposed to auto-purge the leases file once an hour, but this isn't happening for me.  Apparently this is down to a permissions problem - the /var/lib/dhcp directory and contents are ownwd by root:root but the server runs as dhcpd:dhcpd.  I tried changing the ownership as follows:-

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop
sudo chown -R dhcpd:dhcpd /var/lib/dhcp/
sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

but after this the ownership of the directory, dhcpd.leases and dhcpd.leases~ reverted to root:root.

So how do I sort out directory ownership vs the user:group running the dhcpd process to get auto-purge to work?

Comment: Do you have `one-lease-per-client` configured? How many devices are we talking about? What's the lease-time? You should run into few problems deleting or manually editing the lease-file, but I don't know why you'd do it in the first place. 350MB is not _that_ huge. Maybe you also ran into a permissions issue where dhcpd can't rotate the file?

Comment: 37 devices.  default-lease-time is 600 (seconds?!).  No one-lease-per-client set.  I've got a Perl script that greps out the active lease info and it takes 5 minutes to grok the file.

Comment: Looks like permissions - /var/lib/dhcp is owned by root:root but dhcpd is running as dchpd:dhcpd. Thanks.

Comment: 600s? That's short for 37 devices...ok well, I think your question is answered.

Comment: Hmm... so I edited the lease time in etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf, did "sudo chown -R dhcpd:dhcpd /var/lib/dhcp", then "sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart" and the directory and lease files went back to root:root ownership!

Comment: Sounds like the buggy version of isc-dhcp: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1186662

Comment: I updated to the latest available in Ubuntu 14.04 but still got 4.2.4 so I guess I'm stuck until I bite the bullet and rebuild that server.  For now the chown thing should keep things ticking over as long as I don't restart dhcpd. Thanks.

Comment: @kbro: Remember 14.04 is EOL in April, so rebuild it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual [`man dhcpd.leases`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.leases):

> In order to prevent the lease database from growing without bound, the file is rewritten from time to time. First, a temporary lease database is created and all known leases are dumped to it. Then, the old lease database is renamed `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases~`. Finally, the newly written lease database is moved into place.

AFAIK that may fail when file system permissions on the directory `/var/lib/dhcpd` prevent the unprivileged user dhcpd runs as from creating that temporary database there and then the leases file will continue to grow.

Change ownership of `/var/lib/dhcpd` to the dhcpd user.

Comment: sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop ; sudo chown -R dhcpd:dhcpd /var/lib/dhcp/ ; sudo service isc-dhcp-server start - ownership reverts to root:root

Comment: See other comments - seems that Ubuntu 14.04 has a buggy version of isc-dhcp so for now the best I can do is work around the problem by running "sudo chown -R dhcpd:dhcpd /var/lib/dhcp" after restarting the daemon.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to delete it, only remove what's not needed.

- Stop DHCPD server.
- Edit your dhcpd.leases file and remove what entries you no longer need
- Save the file and start DHCPD server.

You can optimize this by editing the file (and not save until ready) and then perform DHCPD stop / file save / DHCPD start in a matter of seconds or even faster. It even worked under 1s for me; that's if you don't want downtime.

Comment: Manually editing the leases file is not a good idea at all.  If it's 350MB like in this case, this isn't practical anyway.

Comment: I can sort such a file in a few minutes and did so in the past. Nothing unpractical about it. I did not mean go line by line. Advanced text processing editors exists since the MS-DOS era.

Comment: Sorry, this is completely nonsensical. There is a problem with the system configuration and this should be fixed in the proper way.

Comment: The case I specified is for a 'no lease time expiration' situation. The initial post did not say that a lease time is set. Some companies want historical data and let very large or infinite lease times.